# How to make both selectors retain their values

Tags: php, select, post, selector

I made this code and would like to make it so that if I choose either of the two selectors for the other one not to be reset to the starting value. 
I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong with the code. Any thoughts?

```
    <?php
      $filter = true;
      $order = "&orderby=post_date&order=DESC";
      if ($sort1 == '' && $sort2 == '' && $sort3 == '') { $sort1 = ' selected="selected"'; }
      if ($_POST['select1'] == 'newest') { $order = "&orderby=post_date&order=DESC"; $sort1 = ' selected="selected"'; $sort2 = ''; $sort3 = ''; }
      if ($_POST['select1'] == 'oldest') { $order = "&orderby=post_date&order=ASC"; $sort2 = ' selected="selected"'; $sort1 = ''; $sort3 = ''; }
      if ($_POST['select1'] == 'most-popular') { $order = "&meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC"; $sort3 = ' selected="selected"'; $sort1 = ''; $sort2 = ''; }

      if ($view1 == '' && $view2 == '' && $view3 == '') { $view1 = ' selected="selected"'; }
      if ($_POST['select2'] == 'list') { $view1 = ' selected="selected"'; $view2 = ''; }
      if ($_POST['select2'] == 'thumbnail') { $view2 = ' selected="selected"'; $view1 = ''; }
    ?>
    <?php if ($filter) { ?>
    <div class="secondNavCategory">
        <nav class="categorymenu">
    <div class="leftNavCategory">
    <form method="post" id="order">
      SORT:
      <select name="select1" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
        <option value="newest"<?=$sort1?>>NEWEST</option>
        <option value="oldest"<?=$sort2?>>OLDEST</option>
        <option value="most-popular"<?=$sort3?>>MOST POPULAR</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    </div>

    <div class="leftNavCategory">
    <form method="post" id="order">
      VIEW:
      <select name="select2" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
        <option value="list"<?=$view1?>>LIST</option>
        <option value="thumbnail"<?=$view2?>>THUMBNAIL</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    </div>
        </nav>
    </div> <!-- secondNavCategory -->
<?php $filter = false; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you forgot to close the if () {}

```
</div> <!-- secondNavCategory -->
<?php } ?> <!-- You are missing this line -->
```

Also you are using undefined variables, check the if they are set with isset($var) and give them a default value if not.

Excepting the notices i get for the undefined variables, it works for me.

EDIT: this works, the problem is that you have 2 forms, and if one is submitted the others value are not submitted, each form that is submitted passes it's values only, I made only one form now, if you want two forms, make hidden inputs in both with each others values and sett them with JS. Or use AJAX

```
<?php
  $filter = true;
  $sort1 = '';
  $sort2 = '';
  $sort3 = '';

  $view1 = '';
  $view2 = '';
  $view3 = '';

  if (isset($_POST['select1'])) $select1 = $_POST['select1'];
  else $select1 = '';

  if (isset($_POST['select2'])) $select2 = $_POST['select2'];
  else $select2 = '';

  $order = "&orderby=post_date&order=DESC";
  if ($sort1 == '' && $sort2 == '' && $sort3 == '') { $sort1 = ' selected="selected"'; }
  if ($select1 == 'newest') { $order = "&orderby=post_date&order=DESC"; $sort1 = ' selected="selected"'; $sort2 = ''; $sort3 = ''; }
  if ($select1 == 'oldest') { $order = "&orderby=post_date&order=ASC"; $sort2 = ' selected="selected"'; $sort1 = ''; $sort3 = ''; }
  if ($select1 == 'most-popular') { $order = "&meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC"; $sort3 = ' selected="selected"'; $sort1 = ''; $sort2 = ''; }

  if ($view1 == '' && $view2 == '' && $view3 == '') { $view1 = ' selected="selected"'; }
  if ($select2 == 'list') { $view1 = ' selected="selected"'; $view2 = ''; }
  if ($select2 == 'thumbnail') { $view2 = ' selected="selected"'; $view1 = ''; }
?>
<html>
    <head><title>My title</title></head>
    <body>
        <?php if ($filter) { ?>
        <div class="secondNavCategory">
            <nav class="categorymenu">
                <form method="post" id="order">
                    <div class="leftNavCategory">
                        SORT:
                        <select name="select1" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                            <option value="newest"<?php echo $sort1; ?> >NEWEST</option>
                            <option value="oldest"<?php echo $sort2; ?> >OLDEST</option>
                            <option value="most-popular"<?php echo $sort3; ?> >MOST POPULAR</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                    <div class="leftNavCategory">
                        VIEW:
                        <select name="select2" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                             <option value="list"<?php echo $view1; ?> >LIST</option>
                            <option value="thumbnail"<?php echo $view2; ?> >THUMBNAIL</option>
                         </select>
                    </div>  
                </form>
            </nav>
        </div> <!-- secondNavCategory -->
        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I forgot to paste that piece of code at the bottom. I did however define the undefined variables: $filter = true; $sort1 = ''; $sort2 = ''; $sort3 = ''; $view1 = ''; $view2 = '';
Still not working though.

Comment: I edited my response, check it now and try the code.It works fine for me.

Comment: You rock Arrok! Yes this worked. I see what you mean by "isset" and also the fact that you put both selectors into the same form. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, what's a "reputation"? I need 15 of them to vote your answer up. (nevermind I read up on it :) )

Answer (score 1):

First thing you have to change the id of the second form. Most of the Browsers get the first available DOM element(In your case first form since both your form id are same). Since you are submitting your form based on onChange event it will work fine but please try to follow the standards.

You have to use Ajax form submit and process the result accordingly and so whole page will not be refreshed and you will not loose the second form selected value.

Regards,
HBKsagar

Comment: Right, I changed the ID names to order1 and order2. 
how exactly do I use the ajax submit form, if I look it up is it pretty self explanatory?

Comment: Made it work! Put both selectors under the same form. And made sure to set the selectors in advance too.

Comment: I am still curious about the Ajax form submission that you mentioned. As much as I pulled this off, if I can make as many things not refresh, it would be good for the website.

Comment: @user2502562 Ajax form is available as a jQuery plugin if you are not planning to build one. Following materials will help you out [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) & [jQuery-form](http://www.w3bees.com/2013/08/submit-form-without-page-refresh-with.html). Hope this helps. :)